# Why is zero-length array allowed only if it's heap allocated?

Tags: c++, arrays

I notice that it's not allowed to create non-heap allocated arrays of zero length.

```
// error: cannot allocate an array of constant length zero
char a[0];
```

I also notice that it's allowed to create heap allocated arrays of zero length.

```
// this is okay though
char *pa = new char[0];
```

I guess they're both guaranteed by the Standard (I don't have a copy of the Standard at hand). If so, why are they so different? Why not just allow a zero-length array on stack (or vice versa)?

Comment: A zero-length array on the heap is a jar too small to fit anything in.  A zero-length array on the stack is like the space between two gallons of water in a tank... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 0 length array isn't very useful.  When you're calculating the
dimension, it can occur, and it is useful to not have to treat the case
specially in your code.  Outside of `new`, the dimension of the array
must be a constant, not a calculated value, and if you know that the
constant is 0, why define it?

At least, that's the rationale I've heard (from people who worked on
it).  I'm not totally convinced: it's not unusual in code to have to
work with symbolic constants whose value isn't known (from a header
file, or even the command line).  So it probably would make sense to
allows arrays of 0 elements.  And at least one compiler in the past has
allowed them, although I've forgotten which.

One frequent trick in C++ is to use such an array in a compile time
assert, something like:

```
char dummyToTestSomeSpecificCondition[ condition ];
```

This will fail to compile if the condition is false, and will compile if
it isn't.  Except for that one compiler (if it still exists); I'll use
something like:

```
char dummyToTestSomeSpecificCondition[ 2 * condition - 1 ];
```

, just in case.

Answer (score 16):

This is addressed in the following Sections of the C++ Standard.

**3.7.3.1/2:**

*[32. The intent is to have operator `new()` implementable by calling `malloc()` or `calloc()`, so the rules are substantially the same. C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer.]*

And also,

**5.3.4, paragraph 7**

*When the value of the expression in a direct-new-declarator is zero, the allocation function is called to allocate an array with no elements.*

---

An Array of size 0 is not allowed by the C++ standard:

**8.3.4/1:**

*"If the `_constant-expression+` (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero."*

In my understanding the rationale behind this seems to be the fact that C++ standard requires that every object must have an unique address(this is the very reason even an empty class object has size of 1).In the case of a non heap zero sized array, no objects need to be created, and hence no address is required to be given to it and hence no need of allowing it in first place.

---

As far as c is concerned, zero length arrays are **[allowed by the c standard](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)**, typically they are used to implement structures having a variable size by placing the zero length array at the end of the structure. If my memory serves my correct it is popularly called as **C struct Hack**.

Comment: My main question actually is, why are they different in two cases above?

Comment: @Eric: Please check the updated answer. It tries to answer your question. Hth.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the main reason why they behave different is that the first one:

```
char a[0];
```

is an array of size 0, and this is forbidden because its size should be by definition 0*sizeof(char), and in C or C++ you cannot define types of size 0.

But the second one:

```
char *pa = new char[0];
```

is **not** a real array, it is just a chunk of 0 objects of type *char* put all together in memory. Since a sequence of 0 objects may be useful, this is allowed. It just return a pointer past the last item, and that is perfectly fine.

To add to my argument, consider the following examples:

```
new int[0][3]; //ok: create 0 arrays of 3 integers
new int[3][0]; //error: create 3 arrays of 0 integers
```

Although both lines would alloc the same memory (0 bytes), one is allowed and the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on compiler implementation/flags. Visual C++ doesn't allow, GCC allows (don't know how to disable).
Using this approach, STATIC_ASSERT may be implemented in VC, but not in GCC:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(_cond) { char __dummy[_cond];}
```

Comment: Static assert is typically implemented by using a negative number. Visual C++ specifically allows zero-sized arrays, although with a warning as being a "non-standard extension".

Comment: No. VC++ doesn't allow zero-sized local arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Even intuitively this makes sense.

Since the heap allocated method creates a pointer on the stack, to a piece of memory allocated on the heap, it's still "creating something" of size: `sizeof(void*)`. In the case of allocating a zero length array, the pointer that exists on the stack can point anywhere, but nowhere meaningful.

By contrast, if you allocate the array on the stack, what would a meaningful zero length array object look like? It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  There is no pointer on the stack, and the pointer returned by `malloc` or `new` has nothing to do with the allocated memory.

Comment: @James: so who holds the address to the area of memory that was allocated by `new` or `malloc`?

Comment: @J T The client who called them.  (Or nobody, in the case of a memory leak.)

Comment: @James: yes obviously. but where is the actual address stored in memory? Somewhere, the address to the heap allocated memory must be recorded. This address is stored in a pointer, on the stack!

Comment: @J T Or in a static variable, or in another dynamically allocated object, or, if the programmer isn't careful, not at all.

Comment: @James: the point of my post was to indicate that there is something to allocate in the case of heap allocation, even if the array size is zero.

Comment: @J T and my point is that there isn't anything to allocate if the array size is zero.  (Except that C++ requires all objects, even 0 length arrays, to have distinct addresses, which usually means allocating something.  But nothing would change if in this if 0 length arrays could be declared on the stack.  In both cases, there is no visible memory that client code could access.)